# Draw topographic profile along transects perpendicular a river

Tags: qgis, profile, transects

I have a DEM; river (shapefile) ;and a shapfile of containing all the transect of length 5km drawn perpendicular to the river at an interval of 300m each. I am using QGIS 3.8.2.

I want to draw topographic profile along each transect. I have tried **Profile tool plug-in** but, it requires all the transects as separate layers (I guess) because for selected polyline it is not working (attached screenshot-selected line is visible in yellow line [image]).

I am attaching the screenshot of QGIS Canvas to have a look on my dataset[image].

Comment: You can hand a line layer to the profile tool.

Comment: Hey @Vince, attached the screenshots. Kindly revisit the question.  Thanks vince

Comment: @Erik, I tried the profile tool for "selected polyline" . But it is not working in my case ( have attached the screenshot-1.

Comment: Did you select a line? Why don't you run it for selected layer?

Comment: @Erik Since my layer has multiple attributes, the selected layer feature draw profile for all the attributes in a single graph. I need to plot graph separately for each attributes. Therefore, I selected a single line form the layer and chose 'Selected polyline' option, but it did not give any result

Comment: I suggest you provide example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend another plugin "RiverGIS" that was designed specifically for preparing a full GIS dataset for HECRAS, including the profiles of river transects. You will need to have access to a PostGIS database to run this plugin, but that's a good idea anyway, and not that hard to setup.

In addition, you mentioned that you already have the line layer of transects, but it's worth mentioning the "StationLines" plugin for creating the transects at user defined widths, and user defined spacing.

Comment: Thanks @Micha,  "StationLines" plugin really worked for me.  As you mentioned about "RiverGIS" plugin and it requires PostGIS database, Could you please tell me what PostGIS database is, and how I can create this database for my datasets so as to RiverGIS.

Comment: Well that another question entirely. PostGIS is a very popular open source spatial database. You'll find plenty of material on the internet to help. I suggest you install PostGIS on your system, and work thru some tutorials. Then, there's a [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgis](Stackexchange tag) for PostGIS questions.